# How to pass array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I trying to pass an array but don't understand why it gives me those errors. The code is also available in [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/8zlOWz)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Max
{
   int max = 0;

   public:
      int getMax(int array[], int size)
      {
          for(int num : array)
          {
                if(num > max)
                    max = num;
          }
          return max;
      }
};

int main( )
{
   Max m;
   int arr[5] = { 5, 3, 2, 7, 6 };
   cout << "Max number is: " << m.getMax(arr,5);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The easiest way is to take a `std::array` or something like `std::vector`. Everything will just work. No implicit decaying to a pointer. No size information loss.

Comment: What errors does it give you?

Comment: use containers (e.g. vectors) if you can. Life will be easy :)

Comment: " it gives me those errors", which are?

Comment: Its big list thats why i pasted ideone link

Answer (score 1):

The problem here as has been mentioned is that passing an array to a function [it decays to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying). The fix that involves the least changes is to pass the array by reference like so:

```
template <int U>
int getMax(int (&array)[U])
```

this fix is probably not the most intuitive for a beginner though. The fix that requires a bit more changes and probably makes more sense to a beginner is to use `std::vector` or `std::array`:

```
int getMax(const std::vector<int> &array)
```

and in `main`:

```
std::vector<int> arr = { 5, 3, 2, 7, 6 };
cout << "Max number is: " << m.getMax(arr);
```

Comment: const reference would be better than passing `vector` by value.

Answer (score 0):

1. `size` argument needs type specified (proper type is `size_t`).
2. `array` in `getMax` function is a pointer (not an array). You can't use range-based `for` loop with it. You have to use regular `for` loop which will make use of `size` argument.

Comment: The issue is that the method does not receive an array *at all*.  You cannot pass arrays to functions; they decay to a pointer.

Comment: I figure you know that, but I don't think the OP does.

Comment: I know that size must have int.. i just missed it.. what i can do instead? can you show me in code?

Comment: I fixed it but it still doesn't compile.. can you please check the ideone link?

Comment: You didn't fix everything. You still use wrong type of `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is the for(:) can not get the size of "int array[]".

You have a size argument, but the begin() & end() can not use it. You must wrap the begin() and end() member functions or just simple it to

```
for(int i = 0; i< size; i++)
{
   int num = array[i];
   if(num > max)
      max = num;
}
```